# How to read data attributes from the button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, button

I'm creating an order system in a PHP generator. There is a list of orders, and on the lines of unconfirmed orders are placed confirmation buttons (`button-potvrdit`), instead of confirmation dates.

When the user presses the button, the program should retrieve the line id (`FormUId`), stored with the button. Then it should update the order, placing current date in the date of confirmation - this part I'll solve later.

I try to follow the reaction on the button click in the handler function, by means of alert(FUI). It shows me a window with "undefined". Could you please tell me what's wrong? Please find the code sample below.
Thanks
Martin

```
if ($fieldName == 'potvrz_ridicem' and $fieldData == NULL) {
  $dataAttributes = sprintf('data-FormUId="%s"', $rowData['FormUId']);
  $customText = '<span class="product-info" style="display: none;" ' . $dataAttributes . '></span>';
  $customText .=  '<button class="btn btn-default button-potvrdit">Potvrdit</button>';
  $handled = true;
}
```

---

```
function prepareInlineButtons() {
  $('button.button-potvrdit').click(function() {
    var self = $(this); 
    var FUI = self.siblings('.product-info').data('FormUId');
    alert(FUI);
    // ... 
  })
}
prepareInlineButtons();
```

Comment: I am a little confused. It looks like you have PHP and javascript trying to run together?

Comment: show the html for it

Comment: try using `console.log` for more information and an easier debugging experience.

Comment: both the pieces of code reside in the same php file and there is no html. this file is machine-generated and has cca 2.000 lines. I don't think it is a good idea to put it here. I will try again to use the console, even it showed me nothing yet. I might did something wrong, I'm really new in this sort of programs.e

Comment: @HowardP: Thanks for getting me to console.log. It shows many useful information and helped me to discover following thing: Data attribute is "data-formuid", contrary to "data-FormUId" as I would expect. After the change to lowercase, the attribute retrieval works. If you could possibly tell me why it is so, I'd be grateful. Otherwise, the issue is SOLVED.